# Solder balls on PCB

Tags: soldering, solder-mask

I have produced a PCB with a thickness of 1.55 mm, using a 5 mils stencil, using SAC 305 solder (2nd reusable solder tin), a furnace peak temperature of ~235°C for all zones (normal recommended heat), and the pads are all home-shaped.

The formation of tin balls happens sometimes; sometimes it clears, and other times it happens 100%. What can we do to reduce this tin ball problem?

[image]

Comment: That normally occurs, when too much solder paste is added to the PCB or the PCB is not uniformly heated. Try to reduce the stencile thinckness in a first step or let a professional manufacturer solder it.

Comment: yeah i know, but this occurs with frequency many times. Our FQC team need to pick it out of PCB, that take so lots of time. Is there any way to reduce their spawn rate?